# Hardware Clock goes in future sometimes

Tags: linux, real-time-clock, hwclock

I have Slackware with kernel version 2.6 in machine. ntpd is off on that machine. I am facing strange issue. Sometimes in a month, hardware clock goes some months ahead, sometimes some years and sometime some minutes. I am unsure about software clock jump because hwclock --hctosys is scheduled at 5 minutes interval.

Same issue was found on Slackware with kernel version 2.4 too. We have checked there is no any other software installed that causes this issue and no virus reported on disk.

Battery cell is ok and new and this issue occurs on different units of same hardware. Any idea if it is some kind of software or kernel issue or RTC hardware related?

Answer (score 1):

One way to check would be to force the kernel to re-read the hardware clock a couple of times. Use [hwclock(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) to do so. If the results are the same each time, then there is indeed a problem. You might have a failing motherboard.

Comment: we have logged this command cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/since_epoch in log file and got some entries with stuck on same time. and got this error on screen "select() to /dev/rtc to wait for clock tick timed out"
After some restarts, its again start working properly. Well before this thing, our script has set hwclock too many times because of hwclock jumps. We made script which monitor epochtime file and sets hwclock when it detect any jump.

Comment: Your hardware is broken, at least from the POV of Linux kernel RTC driver.